# Missing width and height attributes for <../image/path>

Tags: astrojs

I'm working on a blogging website built with [Astro](https://astro.build/). I have two content collections, one called "blog" and one called "tips" that are set up almost identically. Both content collections have corresponding pages where the content is displayed.

Example of tip frontmatter (loading-google-fonts.md):

```
---
draft: false
content: "Tip"
src: "../../assets/tips/google-sign-in/cover.png"
alt: "electric satellite"
publishDate: 2023-06-25
category: "Flutter"
tags: [dart, flutter, appwrite, cross-platform]
---
Google Fonts tip
```

Example of component that displays image from tip collection entry:

```
<Image
      src={tip.data.src}
      alt={tip.data.alt}
      style="height: 200px; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;"
      class="w-full rounded-md"
/>
```

This setup works fine for the blog collection but I'm getting this error for the tips collection:

```
Missing width and height attributes for ../../assets/tips/google-sign-in/cover.png. When using remote images, both dimensions are always required in order to avoid CLS.
```

Astro also gives me this hint which seems a bit misleading since the image is clearly supposed to come from the assets folder:

```
If your image is inside your `src` folder, you probably meant to import it instead. See the Imports guide for more information https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/imports/#other-assets.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to export the new "tips" collection in `content/config.ts`.

```
export const collections = {
  'blog': blogCollection,
  'tips': tipsCollection, // Forgot to add this line
};
```

After updating config.ts, running astro sync, and rerunning the website everything started working again ([source](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/#defining-a-collection-schema)).